# Hide an input field's error message once the user starts editing it

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a login form in which I display any relevant error messages once the user clicks submit. When the user goes back to the input field to edit it, I want to hide the error message.

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="loginForm.$valid && login(loginFrm.userId, loginFrm.password);" novalidate>
    <input type="text"
           name="userId"
           ng-model="loginFrm.userId"
           required
           ng-minlength="3"
           placeholder="User ID"
           autofocus>

    <div ng-show="loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.userId.$invalid">Minimum 3 characters required</div>

    <input type="password"
           name="password"
           ng-model="loginFrm.password"
           required
           ng-minlength="4"
           placeholder="Password">

    <div ng-show="loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.password.$invalid">Minimum 4 characters required</div>
    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

In my current code the error message hides only after the field becomes valid. How do I hide it as soon as the user starts to edit the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the options you got here to hide the message is with `ng-focus` or `ng-change`.
Depends when you want to hide the message. When using `ng-change`, you have to change your `ng-model-options` to allow invalid values. Else the event will not trigger.
I added both options to [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HOflTIJhokh68sYEQDwp?p=preview).

With `ng-focus`

```
  <input type="text"
         name="userId"
         ng-model="loginFrm.userId"
         required
         ng-minlength="3"
         placeholder="User ID"
         ng-focus="main.userIdEdit = true"
         ng-blur="main.userIdEdit = false"
         autofocus>
  <div ng-show="!main.userIdEdit && loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.userId.$invalid">Minimum 3 characters required</div>
```

With `ng-change`

```
<input type="password"
       name="password"
       ng-model="loginFrm.password"
       ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"
       required
       ng-minlength="4"
       placeholder="Password"
       ng-change="main.passwordEdit = true"
       ng-blur="main.passwordEdit = false">
<div ng-show="!main.passwordEdit && loginForm.$submitted && loginForm.password.$invalid">Minimum 4 characters required</div>
```